# How do I get my email to center in Hotmail?

Tags: email, html-email, hotmail

I am testing my HTML email using http://www.emailonacid.com and Hotmail is causing problems.

This table is appearing as left aligned and I can't figure out why:

```
 <div align="center">
     <table align="center" width="200" style="background:red">
       <tr>
         <td>Please Help</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
 </div>
```

It looks fine in IE but not in FF.

Comment: Ok, I will try to be more specific next time and share my code but I am still very thankful for Bruce's answer below. In this case it was a valid issue and I hope this will help others who encounter the same problem.

Comment: This question is helpful. I'm dealing with the exact same issue - how to center html elements in hotmail email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hotmail places your email inside a div with a class named “ExternalClass” - here are the properties they have set on that class:

```
    .ExternalClass{display:inline-block; line-height: 131%};
```

This has no effect on your email when using IE but every other browser the email will not be centered.

To overwrite this simply include this in your embedded CSS:

```
    .ExternalClass {width: 100%;}
```

I found this to be a great resource for other similar Hotmail issues: [Emailology.org](http://www.emailology.org/#2)

Comment: Ah ha that did it, thanks Bruce!  If you were a candy, you'd be a lifesaver!!!